# What does "move ^<" do in Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, command-line-arguments

I accidentally entered this command in a big working directory and got this result:

```
d:\prog>move ^<
       10 file(s) moved.
```

Can someone explain what have I just done? I have no idea :/

Note:

This only seems to happen if there are files in the directory with just an extension (and no name), for example `.a`.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure `move ^<` was the complete command? I get "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." with that command.

Comment: I also get that at other directories, so it seems something related to the directory contents... now I got an idea and created a file named .a, repeating the move ^< command resulted in 1 file(s) moved. So it might do something with files named .something, but I still don't know what it does...seemingly nothing, but I'd be happier if I knew how it worked :)

Comment: Hmm. With a file named `.a`. I can reproduce it. It doesn't actually move anything though ... investigations continue

Comment: -1 do a DIR, make it so it's reproducable / clear how others can reproduce it.  e.g. when I tried it,  even after creating a file you didn't mention, I got an error message http://i.imgur.com/w0qidGr.png  So i'd like to see more info about what's in d:\prog and your windows version

Comment: Normally `<` is the redirect command for stdin. `^` is the escape character so `^<` means a literal `<` character. So `move ^<` should mean move a file called `<` to the current directory. However `<` is not a valid filename ...

Comment: @barlop I can reproduce, I've added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: @barlop. Your test is using `^>` instead of `^<`. You also need a file called `.a` not `a.a`.

Comment: Reproduced on Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the edit! Here is the dir /a output for my d:\prog directory: [dirout](http://pastebin.com/ik5W4HHh) (it is a big mess, but the point is that there are 10 files with the .xyz formatted filename, i believe move ^< acts(?) on these. The command processor might mistakenly interpret the resulting literal < as this .xyz?

Comment: @DavidPostill, `<` and `>` [are wildcards](http://superuser.com/a/995322/362853).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a wildcard, so, matching files are moved. Microsoft documentation (links at the bottom) states

> - **DOS_QM** (> greater than) Matches any single character or, upon encountering a period or end of name string, advances the expression
>     to the end of the set of contiguous DOS_QMs.
> - **DOS_STAR** (< less than) Matches zero or more characters until encountering and matching the final . in the name.

So, your command is *"moving"* (as the target folder is the same as the source there is no real move operation) files without extension, that is, your command is equivalent to `move *.`

Now the next question should be:

- *If the `^<` (or just `"<"`) is selecting files without extension, why `.a` file that has no name, it only has extension, gets selected?*

And the answer is **short names**. Wildcard selection work on long and short names of the files. If you try with `dir /x` to list the files short names, you will *probably* see that the short name for the `.a` file has no extension.

More information

- [Algorithm for Determining If a Character Is a Wildcard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff469448.aspx)
- [Algorithm for Determining if a FileName Is in an Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff469270.aspx)

Comment: Hmm. So why doesn't `dir ^>` match `a.`?

Comment: @DavidPostill, for me `^>` and `">"` match all files with a single character in its name and no extension. If you included the dot in the name (not the extension separator) then the file name has two characters and it is not matched.